# ¿Como puedo obtener el contexto en un módulo que no tiene visibilidad con la clase Application?

Tags: java, android, context

Necesito acceder a un método a través del contexto, pero no tengo forma de acceder a el ya que el módulo en el que se encuentra este método, no tiene visibilidad con el modulo app y tampoco puedo darsela ya que ocasionaria error de dependencia circular:

```java
private static synchronized String createDataPath(String path) {
    File fileDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(path);
    if (fileDir != null) {
        return fileDir.getAbsolutePath();

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Antes ese context lo cogía a través de almacenar el contexto en una variable estática, pero esto me ocasiona un memory leak y ya he visto que no es para nada recomendado hacerlo de esta manera.

Cuando he tenido problemas de contexto accedía a la instancia de la clase Application que me proveía de un contexto, pero en este caso no puedo acceder a la clase Application porque no se encuentra en mi mismo módulo.

La otra opción es pasarle el contexto por parametro del método pero es un proyecto con cientos de clases y métodos, por lo que pasarle el contexto por parametro haría que tuviera que pasarle el contexto a todos los métodos que dependieran de este, creando así una piramide gigantesca, y es lo que trato de evitar, ¿qué otra opción tengo?.

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. No se entiende que quieres hacer ni que te impide hacerlo. Podrías explicar mejor qué necesitas de la clase `Application` y cuál es el problema con las dependencias en gradle? De ser posible agrega algo de código o al menos una descripción de tu arquitectura que explique cómo necesitas propagar los parámetros

Comment: Agrega mas informacion a tu pregunta por favor. Un modulo es una biblioteca de tu proyecto, debes tener visibilidad, agrega como tratas de obtenerlo en la clase que extiende de Application

Comment: @Jorgesys ya he tratado de añadir algo más de información, pero es que no tengo mucho más que explicar, es eso lo que me pasa...

Comment: Todavía falta mucha explicación. Cómo accedes a la clase del módulo B desde el módulo A? En qué te afecta que esté en otro módulo? Necesitas que el módulo B tenga acceso al módulo A? Qué relación tiene tu problema con la clase `Application`? Necesitas el `ApplicationContext` o cualquier `Context`? Por qué pasar el contexto como parámetro ocasionaría propagarlo? Son métodos estáticos? La clase es de algún tipo especial? Qué lenguaje estás utilizando?? Todo sería mucho mas claro si mostraras un ejemplo de cómo y dónde intentas usar esta clase.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem ya le he añadido más detalles, el lenguaje utilizado y un fragmento del código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es mover tu clase `Application` a un módulo independiente y agregarlo como dependencia de los demás módulos. Así podrías usarla de la misma manera que en tu módulo principal. Pero esto sería propagar la mala práctica.

Si seguiste las buenas prácticas, poco debería importarte en qué módulo se encuentra una clase. La forma de tratarla es igual a la de una clase en el mismo módulo.

En un método tan simple como el que muestras, lo ideal es pasarlo como parámetro. Pero no necesitas que toda la cadena de metódos lo tenga como parámetro, solamente lo necesita la clase que lo invoca directamente.

Por ejemplo si tienes una clase A que invoca un método de la clase B y este último invoca el método estático, sólo la clase B necesita tener un context.

Si usas un inyector de dependencias como [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android), simplemente debes agregarle al parámetro la anotación [@ApplicationContext](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#predefined-qualifiers) (o `@ActivityContext`, dependiendo de tus necesidades) y el contexto se pasará automáticante incluso si no hay ninguna referencia a un `Context` en esa clase.

```
public class B {

    private final Context context;

    @Inject
    B(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void example() {
        ClaseEnOtroModulo.createDataPath(context, "path");
    }
}
```

Si en cambio el método es mas complejo o también es invocado por un método estático, deberías seguir las buenas prácticas y convertirlo en un método regular. Entonces de acuerdo al patrón de inyección de depencias, los métodos no deberían tener el parámetro `Context` sino el constructor de su clase dueña.

```
public class ClaseEnOtroModulo {

    private final Context context;

    public ClaseEnOtroModulo(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public synchronized String createDataPath(String path) {
        File fileDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(path);
        if (fileDir != null) {
            return fileDir.getAbsolutePath();    
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Luego la inyectas en el constructor de las clases que lo requieran

```
public class B {

    private final ClaseEnOtroModulo claseEnOtroModulo;

    @Inject
    B(ClaseEnOtroModulo claseEnOtroModulo) {
        this.claseEnOtroModulo = claseEnOtroModulo;
    }

    public void example() {
        claseEnOtroModulo.createDataPath("path");
    }
}
```

En clases que extienden de componentes de android, la forma de inyectar dependencias es así

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Inject
    private ClaseEnOtroModulo claseEnOtroModulo;

    ...    
}
```

Y así puedes seguir replicando este patrón en todos los lugares que lo necesites. A menos que estés abusando de los métodos estáticos, no deberías tener ningún inconveniente.

De esta forma consigues clases independientes, fáciles de testear y nunca tendrías que pasar explícitamente un `Context` como parámetro por más que todas las clases lo tuvieran en su constructor.

Comment: ¿Y no es una mala práctica guardar el contexto en una variable?

Comment: Es mala práctica en variables estáticas pero no en variables regulares, a menos que luego guardes una instancia de esa clase en una propiedad estática. Y en el caso particular del `ApplicationContext` es seguro guardarlo en cualquier parte, incluso en propiedas estáticas, porque este se mantiene constante durante todo el ciclo de vida de la applicación.